# linux IOSTAT double counting AIO write operations?

Tags: linux, aio, iostat

As part of debugging an IO generator, I've run across an odd set of results under RH 6.4 running on x64 hardware (validated on multiple systems):

-- The application uses linux async IO (i.e., non-posix) to access raw disk partitions (/dev/sdb1, O_DIRECT), and is run as root

-- The application reports 100 io/s, and 60% writes.

-- strace of the application reports 100 calls per second to io_submit() and io_getevents(), reflecting 100 AIO operations per second

-- 'dstat --aio' shows 100 ops per second

-- iostat reports 40 reads/sec, as expected, but 120 writes/second, twice as many as expected

-- An earlier implementation, using synchronous IO, does not show "doubled" writes

Is this behavior a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further testing, it appears that this behavior is limited to the (default) CFQ scheduler. Moving to the NOP scheduler brought IOSTAT in line with the other measurement tools.